# Vectors with $\pm 1$-s and the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, vectors, extremal-combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $k < n$ vectors of length $n$, each having each entry equal to $1$ or $(-1)$. Prove that there is a vector of length $n$ with each entry $1$ or $(-1)$ which is not orthogonal to any of the vectors in $S$.

The idea is to use the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz but I cannot find a suitable polynomial - it should contain something like $\prod_{i=1}^k (x \cdot v_i)$, where $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ are the variables and $v_1,\ldots, v_k$ are the given vectors, but I cannot think of an additional suitable term.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong kind of combinatorial nullstellensatz here.
The original paper showing the result, which was linked in Vezen BU's answer, and which can be found [on Noga Alon's web page](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/Publications/Balancing%20sets%20of%20vectors.pdf), uses a more refined form of combinatorial nullstellensatz (Lemma 2.1. in the paper), not on $\lbrace \pm 1\rbrace^n$ as would be expected, but on "halves" of it. For the sake of being self-contained, I reproduce this original proof here, slightly adapted.

Let $U=\lbrace \pm 1\rbrace^n$. First of all, if $n$ is odd then the scalar product of any two vectors in $U$ is always odd, so no two vectors in $U$ are orthogonal, and we are done. So we may assume without loss of generality that $n$ is even.

We will show the contraposite of the statement in the OP, namely that if $V\subseteq U$ is such that any $u\in U$ is orthogonal to at least one $v\in V$, then $|V|\geq n$.

For a sign $\varepsilon \in \lbrace \pm 1\rbrace$, let

$$
U_{\varepsilon} = \bigg\lbrace (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in \lbrace\pm 1\rbrace ^ n \ \bigg| \  x_1x_2\ldots x_n = \varepsilon \bigg\rbrace \tag{1}
$$

Then $U_{-1}\cup U_1$ is a partition of $U$. The revelance of this partition comes from the following lemma :

**Lemma.** A vector $v\in U$ cannot be orthogonal to both a vector in $U_{-1}$ and a vector in $U_1$.

**Proof of lemma.** Suppose not, and that $v\cdot a = v\cdot b=0$ for some $a\in U_{-1},b\in U_1$. Write $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n), a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ Let $C=\lbrace k \ | \ a_k=b_k \rbrace$ and $D=\lbrace k \ | \ a_k \neq b_k \rbrace$, so that $C\cup D$ is a partition of $[|1..n|]$. If we put $c=\sum_{k\in C} v_ka_k$, and $d=\sum_{k\in C} v_ka_k$, then we have $v\cdot a = c+d$ and $v\cdot b = c-d$, and therefore $c=d=0$. Now, a sum of signs equaling zero must have an even numbers of terms, so $|C|$ and $|D|$ are even. But then $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k = \prod_{k=1}^n b_k$ which contradicts the initial hypothesis that $a\in U_{-1}$ and $b\in U_1$. This finishes the proof of the lemma.

Because of the lemma, if we put

$$
V_{\varepsilon} = \bigg\lbrace v \in V \ \bigg| \ \exists u \in U_{\varepsilon}, u \cdot v = 0 \bigg\rbrace \tag{2}
$$

Then $V_{-1}$ and $V_1$ must partition $V$, and we have separately that for any $u\in U_{\varepsilon}$ there is a $v\in V_{\varepsilon}$ orthogonal to $u$.

Say that a polynomial $P$ is multilinear iff all the monomials appearing in $P$ are of degree at most $1$ in all their variables (thus $x_1x_2x_3$ is multilinear but $x_4^2$ is not). Then we have :

**Variant combinatorial nullstellensatz** Suppose $P$ is a multilinear polynomial in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ with degree $\lt \frac{n}{2}$, such that $P=0$ on $U_{\varepsilon}$. Then $P$ is the zero polynomial.

**Proof of the variant combinatorial nullstellensatz.** Clearly the statement for $\epsilon=1$ is equivalent to the statement for $\epsilon=-1$, using the transformation $P\mapsto P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_n)$. So it will suffice to show the statement for $\varepsilon=1$.
Denote by ${\cal P}_n$ the power set of $[|1..n|]$ and by ${\cal P}'_n$ the subset of ${\cal P}_n$ consisting of the even-sized subsets.
Let $I\in {\cal P}_n$ and $J\in {\cal P}'_n$. Let $M_I$ be the monomial defined by $M_I=\prod_{i\in I} x_i$, and let $u_J$ be the element of $U_1$ whose coordinates are $-1$ when the index is in $J$ and $+1$ otherwise. Then, $M_I(u_J)=(-1)^{|I\cap J|}$. The goal is then to show that the matrix $M=(M_{I}(u_J))_{I\in {\cal P}_n,J\in {\cal P}'_n}$ has full rank, but a well-known equivalent condition for that is that $M^{T}M$ be invertible. But it is straightforward to see that $M^{T}M$ is $2^{n-1}$ times the identity, so this finishes the proof of the variant combinatorial nullstellensatz.

Returning to our main proof, for $\varepsilon \in \lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace$, put

$$
F_{\varepsilon}(x)=\prod_{v\in V_{\varepsilon}} v \cdot x 
$$

Then $F_{\varepsilon}$ is zero everywhere on $U_{\varepsilon}$, nonzero everywhere on $U_{-\varepsilon}$, and has degree exactly $|V_{\varepsilon}|$. Now, let $G_{\varepsilon}$ be the polynomial obtained from $F_{\varepsilon}$ by replacing each monomial $x_1^{m_1}\ldots x_n^{m_n}$ with $x_1^{r_1}\ldots x_n^{r_n}$ where $r_j$ is the remainder of $m_i$ divided by $2$.
Then $G_{\varepsilon}$ is zero everywhere on $U_{\varepsilon}$, nonzero everywhere on $U_{-\varepsilon}$, and has degree at most $|V_{\varepsilon}|$.
By the variant combinatorial nullstellensatz above, the degree of $G_{\varepsilon}$ must be at least $\frac{n}{2}$.
Then

$$
|V|=|V_{-1}|+|V_1| \geq \frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2} = n,
$$

which finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the self-contained answer, I was aware of this paper but since it dates before 1999 (the year of the Nullstellensatz), I thought there would be a proof by using classical versions directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**
Let $F$ be an arbitrary field, and let $f = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a polynomial in $F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Suppose that the $deg(f) = \sum_{i \in [n]}t_i$ where each $t_i \in \{0, 1,2,3, \ldots\}$ with the coefficient of $\prod_{i \in [n]} x_i^{t_i}$ nonzero.
Then if $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ are subset of $F$ with $|S_i| > t_i$, there are $s_i \in S_i$, for each $i \in [n]$ s.t.
$$f(s_1, \ldots, s_n) \neq 0.$$

---

**Proof**
Let $S = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be the set of the $k$ vectors.
Define $f(x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)) = (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i + 1)^{n-k} \prod_{i = 1}^{k} (x \cdot v_i)$ if $n$ even and $f(x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)) = (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i)^{n-k} \prod_{i = 1}^{k} (x \cdot v_i)$ if $n$ odd.
Clearly, $f(x) \neq 0$ iff $\prod_{i = 1}^{k} (x \cdot v_i) \neq 0$ iff $x$ is not orthogonal to any of the vectors in $S$.
The degree of $f$ is $n = \sum_{i \in [n]} 1$.
**We need to show that the coefficient of $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} x_i$ is nonzero but honestly I cannot have a rigorous proof for that currently.**
Let $S_1 = \cdots = S_n = \{-1, 1\}$ with $|S_i| = 2 > 1, \forall i \in [n]$.
By the theorem, there are $s_i \in S_i$, for each $i \in [n]$ s.t.
$f(s_1, \ldots, s_n) \neq 0$, completing the proof.

---

Ref: Alon, Noga. "Combinatorial nullstellensatz." Combinatorics, Probability and Computing 8.1-2 (1999): 7-29. ([https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf))

---

**See also**

Alon, Noga. "Tools from higher algebra." Handbook of combinatorics 2 (1995): 1749-1783. ([http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/tools1.pdf](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/tools1.pdf), page 25)

Alon, Noga, et al. "Balancing sets of vectors." IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 34.1 (1988): 128-130.

Comment: I don't think this polynomial works and anyway the presence of +1 should not matter for the parity of $n$ since the coefficient at $x_1\cdots x_n$ does not change and if $f(s) \neq 0$ (which the theorem would give for some $s$), then anyway $s\cdot v_i \neq 0$ for all $i$ regardless of the first term.

Comment: Yes. But first term may be 0....

Comment: This does not matter since the Nullestellensatz says "there is an $s$ with $f(s) \neq 0$" - and this implies that at $s$ the first term cannot be zero.